# PHP - Match a string using regex and then spliting it for database columns

Tags: php, regex, string

I have `"n" (n=very large)` number of html documents which follow a fixed template but not all documents have all the markers of the template. I am just testing to split the html file data to commit to around 20 different columns in database.

```
    <?php

    $html = file_get_contents('test.html');
    $strip = strip_tags("$html","<b>,<p>,<br>,<blockquote>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<u>,<i>");
    /*** 
    other code here for pattern matching and replacement to add distinct MARKERS to the document for splitting document 
    ***/

    $findoc = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text0);

    /*** 
The string REFN/[A-Z]{2}/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4} is replaced with blank space at this stage so not available anywhere at this stage.
code for splitting the document based on markers already in place in $findoc
****/

?>
```

**Now the question:**

Each document has multiple instances of strings like

```
REFN/[A-Z]{2}/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}
```

The first instance of this string may or may not occur before the next marker which is

```
"Completion Date" string
```

All other instances occur anywhere in the document after `"Completion Date"` string. I would want to save the last three part of the string (excluding slashes) as variables `$a11, $a12, $a13` before the pattern replace so that the same can also be submitted to database when the entire data is being committed.

So, basically this has to be after the

```
$strip = strip_tags("$html","<b>,<p>,<br>,<blockquote>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<u>,<i>");
```

How can I do this for only the string which occurs before the string  `"Completion Date"`?

Comment: How about a simple `'~(?s)REFN/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\S*)(?=\s.*?Completing\s+On)~'` ?

Comment: Sorry for the error, I have fixed it.

So, the question is

if REFN/[A-Z]{2}/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4} occurs before "Completion Date" string

reading content of $strip
i would want

$a11 to hold value of [A-Z]{2} second part of the string
$a12 to hold value of [0-9]{4} third part of the string
$a13 to hold value of [0-9]{4} fourth part of the string

Comment: Before we get ahead of ourselves, what are the actual strings? Because most of the time, there is absolutely no reason to go with a potentially [disastrous](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) RegExp if we can just split the string.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Example string:

REFN/AB/0690/1987
REFN/KR/1897/2011
REFN/ZA/2567/2015

and so on. Each file will have distinct string, if it occurs before the "Completion Date" string.

Comment: `'~(?s)REFN/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\S*)(?=\s.*?Completion\s+Date)~'` You could fix it further by specifying that `REFN/[A-Z]{2}/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}` is _not_ a target string but a regular expression.

Comment: In which case it's this `'~(?s)REFN/([A-Z]{2})/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{4})(?=\s.*?Completion\s+Date)~'`

Comment: @rusticnomad so why not split on space, then on slash? No need for RegExp here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example strings you gave, don't use regualar expressions for this, if your data is uniform. Just use string splitting.

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $set = explode('/', $line);
  $code = $set[1];
  $ncode = intval($set[2]);
  $year = intval($set[3]);
}
```

Done. We have absolutely no reason to use regular expressions here.